# Does convolution in Theano rotate the filters?

Tags: theano, keras

I have an 3-channel 5-by-5 image like this:

```
1 1 1 1 1    2 2 2 2 2    3 3 3 3 3
1 1 1 1 1    2 2 2 2 2    3 3 3 3 3
1 1 1 1 1    2 2 2 2 2    3 3 3 3 3
1 1 1 1 1    2 2 2 2 2    3 3 3 3 3
1 1 1 1 1    2 2 2 2 2    3 3 3 3 3
```

And a 3-channel 3-by-3 filter like this:

```
10 20 30   0.1 0.2 0.3   1 2 3
40 50 60   0.4 0.5 0.6   4 5 6
70 80 90   0.7 0.8 0.9   7 8 9
```

When convolve the image with the filter, I am expecting this output:

```
369.6  514.8  316.8
435.6  594.   356.4
211.2  277.2  158.4
```

However, Theano (using keras) gives me this output:

```
158.4   277.2  211.2
356.4   594.   435.6 
316.8   514.8  369.6
```

It seems the output is rotated 180 degrees, I wonder why this happens and how can I get the correct answer. Here is my test code:

```py
def SimpleNet(weight_array,biases_array):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1,1),input_shape=(3,5,5)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(1, 3, 3, weights=[weight_array,biases_array],border_mode='valid',subsample=(2,2)))

    return model
im = np.asarray([
        1,1,1,1,1,
        1,1,1,1,1,
        1,1,1,1,1,
        1,1,1,1,1,
        1,1,1,1,1,
        2,2,2,2,2,
        2,2,2,2,2,
        2,2,2,2,2,
        2,2,2,2,2,
        2,2,2,2,2,
        3,3,3,3,3,
        3,3,3,3,3,
        3,3,3,3,3,
        3,3,3,3,3,
        3,3,3,3,3])

weight_array = np.asarray([
                10,20,30,
                40,50,60,
                70,80,90,
                0.1,0.2,0.3,
                0.4,0.5,0.6,
                0.7,0.8,0.9,
                1,2,3,
                4,5,6,
                7,8,9])

im = np.reshape(im,[1,3,5,5])
weight_array = np.reshape(weight_array,[1,3,3,3])
biases_array = np.zeros(1)

model = SimpleNet(weight_array,biases_array)

sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='categorical_crossentropy')
out = model.predict(im)
print out.shape
print out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the definition of convolution. It has the advantage that if you convolve an image that consists of only zeros except for one single 1 somewhere, the convolution will place a copy of the filter at that position.

Theano does exactly these convolutions, as defined mathematically. This implies flipping the filters (the operation is `filter[:, :, ::-1, ::-1]`) before taking dot products with the image patches. Note that these are not rotations by 180 degrees, at least not in general.

It appears that what you are looking for is cross-correlation, which is taking dot products with the non-flipped versions of the filters at each point of the image.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25619458/perform-the-exact-same-convolution-as-in-theanos-conv2d/26234696#26234696) in which `theano.tensor.nnet.conv2d` is shown to do exactly the same thing as the `scipy` counterpart.

Comment: Thanks. You are right about cross-correlation, this is exactly what I am looking for. I solved this problem by first reverse the weights. For instance, one weight in a channel is reversed to be [90,80,70,60,50,40,30,20,10], this way it gives me the cross-correlation.